# What do the colored bars under the gun symbols represent?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

In the "who killed who" listing that scrolls in the bottom left, under the gun symbol there is a bar. I've noticed that it can be different colors.  So far I've seen blue, purple, and grey.  What does this colored bar mean? I've added a screenshot for reference.

[image: bars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those colors represent the rarity of the gun:

- Base (regular)
- Common (white)
- Rare (blue)
- Legendary (purple)
- Epic (orange)

The higher the level, the more extreme / badass the effects are. In the following screenshot, you can see an Epic gun with the "Eighty Seven" and "Readiness" perks:

[image]

You can [check out this guide](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Call-of-Duty-Infinite-Warfare-Quartermaster/) for more info on crafting weapons ("Prototypes"), but here's the relevant info:

> Each weapon has four Prototype Weapon variants, which must be unlocked   through normal level progression. Once a Prototype Weapon is unlocked, it must then be crafted using Salvage. The rarer the Prototype Weapon, the more Salvage it will cost to craft.
>
> There are four ways to obtain Salvage:
>
> - Within Supply Drops
> - Dismantling Prototype Weapons
> - Acquiring duplicate items in Supply Drops (items are automatically dismantled for Salvage)
> - Completing active missions in Mission Teams